# mod_rewrite redirect one domain to another URL

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have the freemagickey.com and the gogomagickey.com domains both pointing to the same Apache server. Any request to the gogomagickey.com domain should currently redirect to http://www.indiegogo.com/magickey-perfect-password-management/.

I have been reading the mod_rewrite docs and looking at what seems to be similar questions on SO and hacking away at my .htaccess with no joy. Either nothing is redirected or both domains are redirected.

Is it possible to do what need with mod_rewrite in .htaccess?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, and I believe this should do the trick for you:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} gogomagickey\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.indiegogo.com/magickey-perfect-password-management/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: RewriteCond is not required and that line can be removed.

Comment: @ChrisvanChip Removing RewriteCond would redirect all domains which is not what OP wanted.

Comment: That's true. Stupid from me.